# Using Spring Integration to split a large XML file into individual smaller messages and process each individually

Tags: spring, spring-integration, splitter, eai

I am using Spring Integration and have a large XML file containing a collection of child items, I want to split the file into a set of messages, the payload of each message will be one of the child XML fragments.

Using splitter is the obvious but this requires returning a collection of messages and this will exhaust the memory; I need to split the file into individual messages but process them one at a time (or more likely with a multi threaded task-executor).

Is there a standard way to do this without writing a custom component that writes the sub-messages to a channel programatically.

Comment: For people coming across this very old question/answer. Splitters can now handle results of type `Iterable`, `Iterator`, and `Stream`. If any of these types are returned, messages are emitted one-at-a-time.

Answer (score 1):

i have been looking for a similar solution and I have not found either any standard way of doing this. 
Here is a rather dirty fix, if anyone needs this behavior implemented:

1. Split the files manually using a Service Activator or a Splitter with a custom bean.

> ```
> <int:splitter input-channel="rawChannel" output-channel="splitChannel" id="splitter" >
>   <bean class="com.a.b.c.MYSplitter" />
> </int:splitter>
> ```

2. Your custom bean should implement ApplicationContextAware so the application context can be injected by Spring.
3. Manually retrieve the output channel and send each sub-message

> ```
> MessageChannel xsltChannel = (MessageChannel) applicationContext.getBean("splitChannel"); 
> Message<String> message = new GenericMessage<String>(payload));
>
> splitChannel.send(message);
> ```

Comment: For people coming across this very old question/answer. Splitters can now handle results of type `Iterable`, `Iterator`, and `Stream`. If any of these types are returned, messages are emitted one-at-a-time.

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell, thanks for the heads up! One question, since what version of  Spring Integration is this feature supported?

Comment: `Iterator/Iterable` were added in 4.0.4 (Sept 2014). `Stream/Flux` were added in 5.0.0 (November last year). There is also now a `FileSplitter` which [emits file contents a line-at-a-time](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/history.html#x4.2-file-splitter) - since 4.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

For people coming across this very old question. Splitters can now handle results of type `Iterable`, `Iterator`, `Stream`, and `Flux` (project reactor). If any of these types are returned, messages are emitted one-at-a-time.

`Iterator/Iterable` since 4.0.4; `Stream/Flux` since 5.0.0.

There is also now a `FileSplitter` which [emits file contents a line-at-a-time](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/history.html#x4.2-file-splitter) via an `Interator` - since 4.1.2.